# How do I create a local version of the Colab VM?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can run a script via colab on the VM Google provides. I can also run it locally via jupyter, but what needs to be installed on my local machine for it to match the setup of the colab VM?

I can type `!pip freeze` in a colab sheet to see all the Python packages installed, but is there anything else I should do? Is there an easy way to duplicate the colab VM locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Colab with a local Jupyter install. Detailed instructions are here:

http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

In short:

1. Install the Colab Jupyter extension --

   ```
   pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
   jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
   ```
2. Start Jupyter with the following arguments:

   ```
   jupyter notebook \
     --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
     --port=8888 \
     --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
   ```

Then, pick the local runtime option from the connect dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Adding to this, "Google Cloud Platform provides Deep Learning VM images with Colaboratory local backend support preconfigured." 

There is a bit more on the configuration behind in the link below, but I have yet to find the time to deal more on how to replicate this on my ubuntu box. Interested if anyone has gone through this already

https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/deep-learning-images-for-google-cloud-engine-the-definitive-guide-bc74f5fb02bc